# Why does User.last(2) and User.first(2) return the same users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model in which

```
default_scope :order => 'created at desc'
```

I currently have fifty records, ids 1 through 50.

`User.first` returns `User id: 50`.

`User.first(2)` returns `User id: 50` and `User id: 49`

`User.last` returns `User id: 1`

This all makes sense. However,

`User.last(2)` returns `User id: 49` and `User id: 50`, in that order.  Why is that? And how do I return `User id: 1` and `User id: 2`?

Comment: change the scope to :order => 'created_at asc'

Comment: Thanks @Jani. I want to keep the default order the way it is, as I want to keep my index view unchanged. However, I want to be able to access groups of users from both the "top" and from the "bottom" of the list using the console, in case I need to make group updates. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: you can create second scope create_asc unscoped.order('created_at asc) and then use User.create_asc.limit(2). Can you provide sql queries which was executed in both cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common mistake. `User.last(1)` and `User.last()` are not exactly same. `User.last(1)` would give you an array of a single record while `User.last()` would return that record object.

Again, both these methods would behave entirely differently if you have a `default_scope` in your User model.

**`User.last` just works on your default scope, reversing its order**. So the SQL query it fires is:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1
```

On the other hand, `User.last(1)` is similar to writing `User.order('id desc').limit(1)`. And with your `default_scope` in action, the `order by id desc` would come second to the default one. So the SQL it fires would be:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY created_at desc, id desc LIMIT 1
```

So what you really need to do here is remove the default scope using `User.unscoped` as [Kien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13665814/1117398) has mentioned. 
Personally, I avoid using default scope ordering and use explicit scoping instead.

Comment: Thanks very much @atmash for the detailed answer. So the answer is to unscope, then query for the `first(2)`, because they are now ordered by id.

Comment: Not exactly. first(N) and last(N) also show different behaviour. User.last(2) would sort by `id desc` and return top 2 results (49 and 50 in your case). But User.first(2) would return first 2 records that the database returns and would not apply any explicit sort order in the SQL. Chances are that you'll get user with id 1 and 2 but you cannot count on it. I suggest using User.unscoped.order(:id).first(2)

Comment: Thanks @atmaish. I figured that `no default scope == ordered by id`, and this was the true in this case for me, but I guess it's safer to explicitly say `order(:id)`.

Answer (score 1):

[Rubydocs](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods) give you information about first and last methods.

If you last(2) is not working you can try

```
User.find(:order => 'created_at asc', :limit =>2)
```

corrected

```
User.find(:all,:order => 'created_at asc', :limit =>2)  
User.unscoped.order('created_at asc').limit(2)
```

You can pass there many arguments to get what you want.

Comment: This is wrong! There's no sense in using limit option with Model.first() method. `first` implicitly adds limit=1 to the sql. so :limit=>2 would be ignored in your case.

Comment: @atmaish You have right. It should be find instead of first. Corrected answer.

Comment: Thanks @sufleR, but your suggestion returns `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: couldn't find User without an ID`. The solution I went with is `User.unscoped.first(2)`.

Comment: @umezo OK. I usually do not use find so that's why ma answer was still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try `unscoped` method:

```
User.unscoped.first(2) # Get User id=1 and id=2
```

You can check [Remove all scoping](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#removing-all-scoping).

Comment: Thanks @Kien. Turns out, it's actually `User.unscoped.first(2)`, because it's now ordered by id, and ids 1 and 2 now come at the beginning.

Comment: oh, I saw in your question `User.last(2) returns User id: 49 and User id: 50` :)), let me update answer.